# Can we keep python & php both with same apache server?

Tags: php, python, apache

I am familiar with PHP-MYSQL on Apache Server, Now i want to Try PYTHON with Apache & Mysql. My Machine is Already Installed With Apache-PHP-MYSQL. So i want to know is it possible to configure Python on the same server. Please let me know some links for documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), which will allow you to run Python code (built against [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org/)) from httpd.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible, as a matter of fact have you heard of [PiP](https://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/)? I have even called Python without PiP and echo out lines in an HTML table before. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, it should be just about another module to insert into apache.

You can use the old CGI way (http://www.modpython.org/), but nowadays we have a fast [WSGI](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), as mentioned in post above.

I recommend you to check http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html, I think it covers all information you will need.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, you're right Graham, mod_python is not CGI. As far as I know, it does a little bit more than CGI - embeds itself into the server - but is still outdated and there are new, supposingly better ways to do it.